# Shortcuts for finding eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have this matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
7 & -4 & -22 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & -2 & -8 & 2 \\
2 & -2 & -11 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have to calculate eigenvalues for this matrix. Are there shortcuts I can use to make it easier and faster to find the eigenvalues? Am I able to modify this matrix to make it easier to find the determinant which in turn makes it easier to find the characteristic polynomial? I am not looking for an incredibly fringe method, I am just wondering if you truly have to brute force compute with cofactor expansion or you can make the columns or rows be 0 by row manipulation?

Comment: i do not see how finding the determinant would help you to find the characteristic polynomilal. of course knowing the eigenvalues helps to compute both, the determinant and the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: One can see that $\lambda = 3$ is one of the eigenvalues, because that would make the last two rows of $A-\lambda I_4$ to be equal ... It would also make the sum of the first two columns to be 0.

Comment: @Max Do you not compute the characteristic polynomial by computing $ det(A- \lambda I) $?

Comment: You could take the resolvent $A-\lambda I$ and then row-reduce it to upper-triangular form. Then you will have rational functions on the diagonal, whose roots will be the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @user1766555 yes exactly, but $det(A)$ does not help you to calculate $det(\lambda I - A)$. you wrote: "... to find the determinant which in turn makes it easier to find the characteristic polynomial? ..." and my comment does refer to this passage.

Comment: @Max I meant, to ask instead: Is it possible to modify $A$ to make it easier to find $det(\lambda I - A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda=3$ is an eigenvalue because 
$$A-3I_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -4 & -22 & 4 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -2 & -11 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & -11 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$
has rank 2; in particular, $\lambda = 3$ has algebraic multiplicity at least 2 (because the geometric multiplicity is $2$.)

The last column of $A$ is a linear combination of the first three columns, hence the determinant is 0. That means that a third eigenvalue is 0. Since the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace (in this case, 6), the fourth eigenvalue is also 0.

Added to answer: the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial  $P_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I_4)$. In this case, there are four (possibly complex) roots, counted with multiplicities, and their sum is the trace of the matrix $A$, namely 6. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, $\det{A} = 0$. But then $0 = \det{A} = P_A(0)$, hence $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue. Finally, $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue with *algebraic* multiplicity two. Then the *geometric* multiplicity is *at most* two, but can be one - as is the case in this example, as the eigenspace $E_0$ is of dimension one. The matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: I still don't understand why 0 is an eigenvalue if the determinant of A is 0, also on why 0 is the 4th eigenvalue? What theorem is this under? Also, if 0 is the 4th eigenvalue, wouldn't that mean there would have to be 2 eigen vectors?

Comment: Ah, I found out that the Invertible Matrix theorem states that if the matrix isn't invertible, then there is an eigenvalue of 0. However, I still don't see why there's a 4th eigenvalue.